# Status of Airflow task within the dag

Tags: airflow

I need the status of the task like if it is running or upforretry or failed within the same dag. So i tried to get it using the below code, though i got no output...

```
Auto = PythonOperator(
    task_id='test_sleep',
    python_callable=execute_on_emr,
    op_kwargs={'cmd':'python /home/hadoop/test/testsleep.py'},
    dag=dag)

logger.info(Auto)
```

The intention is to kill certain running tasks once a particular task on airflow completes.

Question is **how do i get the state of a task like is it in the running state or failed or success**

Answer (score 23):

I am doing something similar. I need to check for one task if the previous 10 runs of another task were successful.
*@taky2* sent me on the right path. It is actually fairly easy:

```
from airflow.models import TaskInstance
ti = TaskInstance(*your_task*, execution_date)
state = ti.current_state()
```

As I want to check that within the DAG, it is not neccessary to specify the dag.
I simply created a function to loop through the past n_days and check the status.

```
def check_status(**kwargs):
    last_n_days = 10
    for n in range(0,last_n_days):
        date = kwargs['execution_date']- timedelta(n)
        ti = TaskInstance(*my_task*, date) #my_task is the task you defined within the DAG rather than the task_id (as in the example below: check_success_task rather than 'check_success_days_before') 
        state = ti.current_state()
        if state != 'success':
            raise ValueError('Not all previous tasks successfully completed.')
```

When you call the function make sure to set `provide_context`.

```
check_success_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='check_success_days_before',
    python_callable= check_status,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
)
```

**UPDATE:**
When you want to call a task from another DAG, you need to call it like this:

```
from airflow import configuration as conf
from airflow.models import DagBag, TaskInstance

dag_folder = conf.get('core','DAGS_FOLDER')
dagbag = DagBag(dag_folder)
check_dag = dagbag.dags[*my_dag_id*]
my_task = check_dag.get_task(*my_task_id*)
ti = TaskInstance(my_task, date)
```

Apparently, there is also an api-call by now doing the same thing:

```
from airflow.api.common.experimental.get_task_instance import get_task_instance
ti = get_task_instance(*my_dag_id*, *my_task_id*, date)
```

Comment: You're an Airflow Hero dude thank you for providing such detail and especially thank you for posting that Update with the additional code. You're a life saver!

Comment: Thanks @Krischl for this reply. When calling a task from another DAG, how do you determine its `date`? I tried using `check_dag.get_last_dagrun().execution_date`, but `get_last_dagrun` returns None.

Comment: @A. Debugne I dont see why your approach shouldn't work unless your DAG has never run. You might also want to check `check_dag.latest_execution_date`. If you know your DAG you might also get around manually by changing the datetime-object `date = date.replace(hour=*my_hour*,minute=*my_minute*)`

Comment: How do you get the status as a string for use in, say, an email operator, or just to print to logs?

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at the code responsible for the command line interface operation suggested by Priyank.

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/2318cea74d4f71fba353eaca9bb3c4fd3cdb06c0/airflow/bin/cli.py#L581

```
def task_state(args):
    dag = get_dag(args)
    task = dag.get_task(task_id=args.task_id)
    ti = TaskInstance(task, args.execution_date)
    print(ti.current_state())
```

Hence, it seem you should easily be able to accomplish this within your DAG codebase using similar code.

Alternatively you could execute these CLI operations from within your code using python's `subprocess` library.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, I think I know what you're doing and I don't really agree with it, but I'll start with an answer.

A straightforward, but hackish, way would be to query the task_instance table. I'm in postgres, but the structure should be the same. Start by grabbing the task_ids and state of the task you're interested in with a db call.

```
SELECT task_id, state
FROM task_instance
WHERE dag_id = '<dag_id_attrib>'
  AND execution_date = '<execution_date_attrib>'
  AND task_id = '<task_to_check>'
```

That should give you the state (and name, for reference) of the task you're trying to monitor. State is stored as a simple lowercase string.

Comment: I am creating an SSH connection and executing scripts on a remote server. When I "clear" a running task, task stops but the script continues to run on the remote server. Therefore i thought of checking the status of the task to kill the script. Is there a better approach ?

Comment: I guess I just don't like the idea of having a busy wait taking up a task slot on the worker. This job seems like a single discrete step (spin up, execution, terminate) from the airflow perspective. Are you running multiple jobs on the same cluster while it is up? I don't really have a better solution atm (although I'm also building an EMR operator/hook, so maybe I will). This question, and my answer (regular busy-checking of a database table) just raises a lot of red flags to me.

Comment: On the cluster I will be submitting one job at a time but in a situation where i need to kill/stop a running task, from the UI, I am unable to kill/stop the task that is running on the remote server. Reason being, when the airflow task runs, the task created another process id for the ssh connection and so when i "clear" the task from the Airflow UI, the parent process gets killed where as the SSh connection is still up and the job is executing. I am not sure how to handle the situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command line Interface for this:

```
 airflow task_state [-h] [-sd SUBDIR] dag_id task_id execution_date
```

For more on this you can refer official airflow documentation:

http://airflow.incubator.apache.org/cli.html

Comment: I need it within a dag. Not on the CLI. I have to kill tasks based on the status and hence I need State of the task

Comment: @ChetanJ you could call the cli from a PythonOperator task using subprocess in the callback function. Possibly not a great idea though.

Comment: Lol just use the BashOperator not the PythonOperator.

Comment: may be without execution_date?