# Skip run if DAG is already running

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a DAG that I need to run only one instance at the same time. To solve this I am using max_active_runs=1 which works fine:

```
dag_args = {
    'owner': 'Owner',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 01, 1, 12, 00),
    'email_on_failure': False
}

sched = timedelta(hours=1)
dag = DAG(job_id, default_args=dag_args, schedule_interval=sched, max_active_runs=1)
```

The problem is:

When DAG is going to be triggered and there's an instance running, AirFlow waits for this run to finish and then triggers the DAG again.

My question is:

Is there any way to skip this run so DAG will not run after this execution in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: You can place a task in your dag, which checks if there is any dag with the same dag_id having state as 'running' in dag_run table of airflow database, if there are two instances running for the same dag you can make the dag to fail.

Comment: @ShahbazAli that's a good idea! But how I can find DAG ID and how can I query this? Thanks!

Comment: And note that they are not running together since I am setting max_active_runs to 1. AirFlow is just holding the trigger until the previous one finishes.

Comment: I can try something like this but not sure if it's the best way to solve this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43732642/status-of-airflow-task-within-the-dag

Answer (score -3):

This is just from checking the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html#airflow.models.dag.DAG), but it looks like you only need to add another parameter:

```
catchup=False
```

> catchup (bool) – Perform scheduler catchup (or only run latest)?
> Defaults to True