# Execution time and state of a specific task within a airflow dag

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I would like to extract all execution time of a particular task in an Airflow Dag. I would prefer to do it by writing another Dag.

I have used the following Dag to extract the status and execution time of another Dag

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas_gbq
from google.cloud import storage as gcs
from google.cloud import bigquery

dag_id = 'my_dag'
dag_runs = DagRun.find(dag_id=my_dag)
        
# Declare empty array

arr = []
arr1 = []

for dag_run in dag_runs:
    arr.append(dag_run.state)
    arr1.append(dag_run.execution_date)
 

dag_info = {'time': arr1, 'dag_status': arr}

df = pd.DataFrame(dag_info)

## Keep failed and successful dag runs    
df_status = df[(df.dag_status == "failed") | (df.dag_status == "success")] 

df_status.loc[df_status['dag_status']=='success','flag'] = 0
df_status.loc[df_status['dag_status']=='failed','flag'] = 1

### Code to save the table in Bigquery


return None
```

I would like to do same but this time to extract a task information for 'my_dag'. I have tried solution given [Status of Airflow task within the dag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43732642/status-of-airflow-task-within-the-dag) but it returns "None", although I know the task and dag is running.

```python
def task_status_check(**kwargs):

        ##### TESTING. ####

        import pandas as pd
        import datetime

        my_date = datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 28)

        my_dag_id = 'my_dag'
        my_task_id = 'my_task'


        dag_folder = conf.get('core','DAGS_FOLDER')
        dagbag = DagBag(dag_folder)
        check_dag = dagbag.dags[my_dag_id]
        my_task = check_dag.get_task(my_task_id)

        for n in range(1, 500, 2):

            time_delta = timedelta(minutes = n)
            my_date_1 = my_date + time_delta 
            ti = TaskInstance(my_task, my_date_1)

            print("######################")
            print(ti.current_state())
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What does `TaskInstance(my_task, my_date_1)` return? Can you check this value for some of iterations in the loop `print(ti)`?

Comment: Can you also provide Composer image version?

Comment: @Nick_Kh Thanks for the reply. I did checked the print(ti). Here is one example output 

<TaskInstance: my_dag_id.my_task_id 2020-09-28 04:36:00+00:00 [None]>

So it makes sense that print(ti.current_state()) is none because it's [None]. 
I was wondering if it's possible to get the task information without mentioning time as I did for the Dag.

The composer version is "composer-1.7.3-airflow-1.10.2"

Thanks

Comment: ```<TaskInstance: my_dag.my_task 2020-09-28 04:36:00+00:00 [None]>```

Comment: ```composer-1.7.3-airflow-1.10.2```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue here in [TaskInstance()](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/models/taskinstance/index.html#airflow.models.taskinstance.TaskInstance) model but not the custom code logic enclosed in `task_status_check()` function. Basically `TaskInstance()` class offers a variety of Airflow tasks managing features leveraging [SQLAlchemy OMR](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) Python tool which performs the query against entire Airflow metadata DB fetching the records from `task_instance` SQL table, looking through the source code you might get [#L203](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/9860719c72be1cab7cd8d117e26457e7207b2be3/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L203) that reflects this.

I've tried your code in the very common similar scenario and faced with the same `None` returned state. Reviewing the user's efforts mentioned in the initial question Stack [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43732642/status-of-airflow-task-within-the-dag) and getting deeper into the problem I've adjusted `get_task_instance()` to check the behavior, pointing this function to extract the state for the particular Airflow task. As long as `get_task_instance()` is an experimental [package](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/api/common/experimental/get_task_instance.py), seemingly it is invoking `TaskInstance()` class to discover the task state:

```python
def task_check(**kwargs):
  import datetime
  from datetime import timezone
  from airflow import configuration as conf
  import logging
  from airflow.api.common.experimental.get_task_instance import get_task_instance
  
  my_date = datetime.datetime('yyyy', 'mm', 'dd', 'hour', 'min', 'sec')
  my_date = my_date.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc) 

  my_dag_id = "Dag_id"
  my_task_id = "Task_id"
  ti = get_task_instance(my_dag_id,my_task_id,my_date)
```

I've checked that the request to Airflow DB was successful, however `get_task_instance` function returns the same `None` state:

> {python_operator.py:114} INFO - Done. Returned value was: None

Meanwhile, doing the further research, considering the other methods for extracting the state for Airflow tasks and they just kept this job fine.

- Airflow [command-line](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli-ref#task_state) executor, adjusted to run on one of the
  Composer workers:

  ```
  kubectl -it exec $(kubectl get po -l run=airflow-worker -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}' \
      -n $(kubectl get ns| grep composer*| awk '{print $1}')) -n $(kubectl get ns| grep composer*| awk '{print $1}') \
      -c airflow-worker airflow task_state <Dag_ID> <Task_ID> 2020-09-27T23:59:21+00:00
  ```
- Querying the metadata MySQL `task_instance` accordingly:

```sql
   SELECT task_id, state, execution_date
   FROM task_instance
   WHERE dag_id = 'dag_id'
   AND DATE(execution_date) = 'execution_date'
   AND task_id = 'task_id'
```

Comment: Nick_Kh, Thanks for the deep dive in the issue. I will try the other methods you mentioned that is working. I exactly do not know where I can execute the SQL query on GCP Composer. I would appreciate your input. Thanks again

Comment: I believe that I've already explained the process of connecting to MySQL Ailrflow metadata schema in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63882534/9928809) answer, hope it will help you to overcome the issue. If you find my answer was effortful to give more details to the problem evidence then consider [accept/up vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) it, helping the other contributors with their research.

Comment: Hi @Nick_Kh, thanks for pointing me to related post. I will look into it. As I still could not come up with a solution hence I up voted your effort. Thanks Again